Angular form not binding functions properly
I tried making this little form and intent to call a function when submitting, but it won't do call even the starting console.log.
Worth noting, nothing is being logged, not the console.logs inserted, nor browser console errors, on the DOM the form element appears without the onSubmit property. I tried using 2 functions with different submit approaches but neither worked. This is a child component of the root component and the root component has nothing other than imports.
This is the html
`
<div class="container">
    <form [formGroup]="users" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" (submit)="logEvent($event)" >
        <input type="text" formControlName="user" id="user" style="display: block;">
        <input type="text" formControlName="pword" id="pword" style="display: block;">
        <input type="text" formControlName="nombre" id="nombre" style="display: block;">
        <input type="text" formControlName="rol" id="rol" style="display: block;">
        <button type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>
</div>



And this is the component.ts file
@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-user',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule],
  templateUrl: './create-user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-user.component.css']
})
export class CreateUserComponent implements OnInit{
  users;

  constructor( private userService: UserService, private fb: FormBuilder ) {
    this.users = this.fb.group({
      user:'',
      pword:'',
      nombre:'',
      rol:'',
    });


  }

  async onSubmit(): Promise<void> {
    
    console.log('on submit called')
    console.log(this.users.value);
    if (this.users.valid) {
      console.log('valid form');
    }
  };

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //console.log(this.users);
}

  logEvent(event: Event) {
    console.log('log event', event);
  }
}


issue not reproducible Stackblitz Demo

Use only (submit) event. NOTE: not make it "async".

From your component imports I can see you bring in both ReactiveFormsModule and FormsModule - this is unnecessary and could be causing the issues you are seeing as the two packages may clash.
Generally for all forms I use ReactiveFormsModule and follow roughly the same pattern (notice the separation of concerns with dedicated methods being responsible for a single task):

// define a type for the form
export interface IUserForm {
   user: FormControl<string>,
   pword: FormControl<string>,
   nombre: FormControl<string>,
   rol: FormControl<string>
}

// import FormBuilder
private fb = inject(NonNullableFormBuilder);
// declare your typed form and initialise it
public userForm!: FormGroup<IUserForm>;

ngOnInit(): void {
  // dedicated build method for the form
  this.buildForm();
}

private buildForm(): void {
  this.userForm = this.fb.group({
    user: [''],
    pword: [''],
    nombre: [''],
    rol: ['']
}

public handleSubmit(): void {
  // handle validation 
  this.userForm.markAllAsTouched();
  if(this.userForm.invalid){
    return;
  } else {
    this.createNewUserRequest();
  }
}

private createNewUserRequest(): void {
  // map your form values to your request
  const request: CreateUserDto = {}  
  this.sendRequest(request);
}

private sendNewUserRequest(request: CreateUserDto): void {
 // call your API and handle response
}

For the template markup I have found that I tend to rely more on a dedicated click binding for the submit button: this allows me to place the button anywhere in the template, including outside of the form element.

<div class="container">
  <div class="form-container">
    <form [formGroup]="users">
      <input type="text" formControlName="user">
      <input type="text" formControlName="pword" >
      <input type="text" formControlName="nombre" >
      <input type="text" formControlName="rol" > 
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="form-actions">
     <button (click)="handleSubmit()">submit</button>
  </div>
</div>



This was weird, I tried removing one and then removing the other but it was still malfunctioning, I made the component entirely from scratch with just ReactiveFormsModule and it worked fine.
Gonna do forms with ReactiveForms from now on.

When dealing with FormGroup always make sure you have it initialized, if not you will get a console error and the form won't be initialized properly.
You can reinitialize it with proper values, in either ngOnInit, constructor or other hooks. But the initial value must be defined.
...
export class CreateUserComponent implements OnInit{
  users = new FormGroup({}); // <- changed here!
  // users = this.fb.group({}); // <- changed here!

  constructor( private userService: UserService, private fb: FormBuilder ) {
    ..

